# Wifi Light Switch won't fit in my electrical box

Tags: electrical, switch, junction-box

I am fitting wifi light switches.  My back boxes are square metal, but the dimmer switches are all round euro style.  Is there a way to utilise these without repairing the wall.  Perhaps a converter widget of some sort?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Can you include an image of the box and switch you're talking about?

Comment: most of europe is on 240vac, so it might be more complicated than physical reconciliation.